# LLVM: null node in the leaf position of a callgraph

Tags: llvm

I am trying to iterate through a callgraph in a DFS way, and here is my code(simplified):

```cpp
 CallGraph CG = CallGraph(M); 
 for (auto IT = df_begin(&CG), EI = df_end(&CG); IT != EI; IT++) {
     if(Function *F = IT->getFunction()){
         dbgs() << "fun name " << F->getName() << "\n";
     }else{
         dbgs() << "fun address " << IT->getFunction() << "\n";
     }
     dbgs() << "distance " << IT.getPathLength() << "\n"
 }
```

I got the printed result from the console like this:

```
fun address 0x0 
distance 1 
fun name s2n_alpn_send 
distance 2 
fun name s2n_calculate_stacktrace 
distance 3 
fun address 0x0 
distance 4 
fun name strlen 
distance 3 
fun name s2n_stuffer_write_uint16 
distance 3
```

I wonder why the DFS goes to 0x0 with a distance of 4, why is there a null point in the leaf position?

Besides, I observed this because I was trying to collect all the functions that are being called by one function together, and I am doing this by iterating the DFS graph and collecting the functions in the same path. However, I found that there is some path/node missing compared to `CG.dump()`.

Answer (score 1):

`nullptr` the `CallGraph` can be either the `ExtrenalCallingNode` or the `CallsExternalNode`. This means that your function could be called from outside the `Module` or that it may call a function from outside the `Module`.